# In-App Payments for Android Amazon AppStore

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, amazon-appstore

I'm familiar with the in-app payments from google proper
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

But are there other solutions which can be implemented for apps distributed through the amazon marketplace? Alternatively, does the google IAP system work if the app wasn't distributed through the google marketplace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google's IAB uses the Android Market app, and requires a Google checkout account (possibly works with carrier billing too). If the Market app is not available it is not going to work. Even if it is, calling the Android Market from an app targeting the Amazon appstore will get 
your app rejected. In short, forget about IAB on Amazon.

You might be able to use PayPal or other third-party solutions, but the Amazon terms of use 
probably don't allow this (especially since you are not allowed to set your own prices). Read the terms thoroughly, better yet, consult with a lawyer.

Comment: Apparently this is in the works for Amazon: http://www.amazon.com/gp/html-forms-controller/AmazonAppstore-IAPrequest

Comment: Nice! that's exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: I don't think the question was really answered fully. "Does the Google IAP system work if the app wasn't distributed through the google marketplace"? I don't think this was answered. I don't even understand this: "calling the Android Market from an app targeting the Amazon appstore...". Bottom line: If Market app is on the phone does Google IAB work regardless of the source of the app that the user is using for IAB? Imagine you are just unlocking a level and using IAB for that. Does it matter where the app came from (Market, Amzazon, downloaded from Web, etc)?

Comment: @Fraggle Simple: if you submit an app that has even a link to the Android Market, let alone IAB, to Amazon, it will be rejected. So there is no way to install an app with Google IAB from Amazon. Technically, if you have the app published in the Android Market and you side load the same app, signed with the same certificate, and using the same IAB public key it _should_ work. But that could change anytime, so don't count on it. (Android has an API to check if an app was installed from the Android Market)

Comment: @NikolayElenkov: Thanks, that helps. Although sort of a nightmare from a Developer/Publisher standpoint. Have to implement different in app payment solutions for every different store you have the app published on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RoboBillingLibrary](https://github.com/christopherperry/RoboBillingLibrary) to publish across Google Play and the Amazon Appstore, with minimal effort. All the details are abstracted away for you.