# how to implement in app billing for amazon store in android app

Tags: android

I want to implement in App billing for Amazon app store in my android app.Is there any sample code for implementing in app billing for android app  for Amazon store.  I have tried RoboBilling library for in app billing but it is not compiling correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The question:**

So you are looking for a method to perform in app purchasing for Amazon Store using Google Android Platform.

**What you need:**

So you will need the procedure to implement IAP (In App Purchasing) by incorporating the API into your project.

**How to achieve what you need:**

The detailed procedure to do this is explained with images by  [Amazon here - Implementing In App Purchasing - Android](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs/quick-start). The sample code you need to achieve this is also mentioned in this Amazon website link. So you can get a working idea.

Additionaly, you can refer this previously answered question on Stackoverflow [In-App Payments for Android Amazon AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654558/in-app-payments-for-android-amazon-appstore).

Comment: In my app In App Google Play Billing is already implemented in which a IInAppServiceBilling.aidl is used. would i have to use the same for Amazon App store or there is no requirement for this in case of Amazon store.

Comment: The Google Play Billing Library won't help in the case of Amazon App Store. You'll have to implement Amazon's In App Purchasing SDK in your android project.

Comment: @SandeepDhiman : Kindly accept the answer if you feel, it answered your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Mobile App SDK includes sample apps implementing the In-App-Purchasing API for each type of IAP item: consumables, entitlements & subscriptions.  You can download this SDK from the link below.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/sdk